# How to transform a PHP loop to a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a PHP loop work for me in MySQL. Currently all visits to a website via a specific URL parameterare logged into a table along with the date and time of the visit. I am rebuilding the logging procedure to only count the visits via one specific parameter on one day, but I'll have to convert the old data first.

So here's what I'm trying to do: The MySQL table (let's call it `my_visits`) has 3 columns: `parameter`, `visit_id` and `time`.
In my PHP code, I've created the following loop to gather the data I need (all visits made via one paramter on one day, for all parameters):

```
foreach (range(2008, 2014) as $year) {

    $visit_data = array();
    $date_ts    = strtotime($year . '-01-01');

    while ($date_ts <= strtotime($year . '-12-31')) {

        $date     = date('Y-m-d', $date_ts);
        $date_ts += 86400;

        // count visit data
        $sql  = 'SELECT parameter, COUNT(parameter) AS total ' .
                'FROM my_visits ' .
                'WHERE time BETWEEN \''.$date.' 00:00\' AND \''.$date.' 23:59\' '.                  
                'GROUP BY parameter ORDER BY total DESC';

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute(array($date));

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

             $visit_data[] = array(
                'param'       => $row['parameter'],
                'visit_count' => $row['total'],
                'date'        => $date);
        }

        $stmt->closeCursor();
    }
}
```

Later on, the gathered data is inserted into a new table (basically eliminating `visit_id`) using a multiple `INSERT` (thanks to SO! :)).

The above code works, but due to the size of the table (roughly 3.4 million rows) it is very slow. Using 7 * 365 SQL queries just to gather the data seems just wrong to me and I fear the impact of just running the script will slow everything down substantially.

Is there a way to make this loop work in MySQL, like an equivalent query or something (on a yearly basis perhaps)? I've already tried a solution using GROUP BY, but since this eliminates either the specific dates or the parameters, I can't get it to work.

Comment: What is `$datum`? You don't have a placeholder in the query for it. And why aren't you using placeholders for `$date`?

Comment: @Barmar I'm so sorry, this happens to me all the time when I try to clean up my code for SO. I'm constantly overlooking 1 or 2 occurrences. What exactly do you mean by placeholders?

Comment: Placeholders are the `?` or `:name` things you put in PDO queries, that get replaced by the parameters in the `execute` call.

Comment: I.e. it should be `WHERE time BETWEEN CONCAT(?, " 00:00") AND CONCAT(?, " 23:59")`

Comment: just for my understanding of the context (I think Niet already gave the best concrete answer): isn't it enough to run this script once, insert the result in a new, much smaller table with date and paramater as primary key (or indexed columns), then use the condensed table in concrete use cases? that way you would only need to update the condensed table once daily with the newest data

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the clarification. And for the code snippet as well, I've never seen `CONCAT` in use before. I think building the query string the way I did became kind of a bad habit. Thanks to you I know how to avoid it from now on. :)

Comment: @cypherabe Yes, indeed it is. That's exactly what I'm after. Eventually we're going to delete the old tables since they're taking up to much disk space - I just have to migrate the old data first for the sake of statistics relying on this data, and going at it my way (as described in the post) would've taken 7 * 365 * 2 seconds = a veeeeeery long time. (I hope I got the meaning of your comment right?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `GROUP` further.

```
SELECT `parameter`, COUNT(`parameter`) AS `total`, DATE(`time`) AS `date`
FROM `my_visits`
GROUP BY `parameter`, DATE(`time`)
```

You can then execute it once (instead of in a loop) and use `$row['date']` instead of `$date`.

This also means you don't have to update your code when we reach 2015 ;)